Why in port forwarding in VirtualBox I can't set both equal host port and guest port?
Name: Anything you want. example for ssh, say “ssh"
Protocol: Type of protocol [ for ssh: TCP ]
Host IP: provide hostname from which host you want to connect to [ over here: 127.0.0.1 ]
Host Port: On what port of that Host you want to connect to remote port [ example: 60022 ]
Guest IP: Leave it Blank
Guest Port: To what port you want to connect from the above host. [ for ssh, the default 22 ]

So I have this parameters and e.g. I wanna do SSH connections, I wanna go to 22 port, so when I'll call to localhost:22 Virtual Machine will be listening to that port and then connection must be. But it doesn't.
This is my VM settings and this is result.
#Wants password, I key in right, but it tell that it's incorrect
PS C:\Users\User> ssh -p 22 hodini@localhost
hodini@localhost's password:
Permission denied, please try again.

#Also there is no such user at all but it still require from me password?
PS C:\Users\User> ssh -p 22 not_existing_user@localhost
not_existing_user@localhost's password:
Permission denied, please try again.

#Switched host's port to 2222
PS C:\Users\User> ssh -p 2222 hodini@localhost
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 6.5.0-26-generic x86_64)

I think it because it works not like I think. Like 22 port on host, but there since host and guest in one PC we can't divide singe port to two devices?
I've heard that there is a NAT connection and with this connection guests can't see the host and the host can't see the guests, both can access the global internet. But I don't understand why this is done. We become a router and the guests are on the local network? It would be nice if someone could explain on fingers why this is so, instead of giving some complicated wording etc etc etc, here are simple examples
I've also heard that there are other types of connections where you can somehow directly link host and guest, but it's not about NAT.
I wanna call for 22 port and 22 port on both host and guest, but I think it's not what I expect...

You already have a service running on port 22, so the binding to your VM cannot succeed. What's happening in the first instance is that the existing service collects your login request. In the third instance it's the port forwarding to your VM that has accepted your login request - which obviously does what you expect.
My guess would be that your Windows host is already running SSH as a service on port 22. You can check this by running SERVICES.MSC, searching for OpenSSH SSH Server and seeing if it's Running. You can also check by leaving the port forwarding at the alternate 2222, and seeing if you get a password prompt when connecting to port 22. (If you do, then it's clearly not your expected port forwarded service as that's listening elsewhere.)
